# debugging with netbeans and xdebug won't work - netbeans don't start browser

Tags: netbeans, xdebug

Try and error.. did not helped me after 2 hours even with "googling" around. No one seems to have my problem or there is a easy solution that i don't see.

My phpinfo() show xdebug just fine:

```
version         2.1
xdebug.remote_enable    On
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp
xdebug.remote_host      localhost
xdebug.remote_mode      req
xdebug.remote_port      9000
```

My netbeans listen to port 9000 (but just on ipv6; may be this is the problem):

```
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      5290/java
```

Netbeans is reachable through telnet:

```
$ telnet localhost 9000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
```

But netbeans does not start the browser until i click the "stop" button. Then it opens up a browser with ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug. How to disable ipv6 for netbeans? I don't want to disable the entire ipv6 support (ipv6 support in enabled in phpinfo()). Any other ideas?

Version:

```
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Apache: 2.2.22
PHP-CGI: 5.3.10
Netbeans: 7.2
Java: 1.7.0_05
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem as the browser not coming up and following is what fixed the problem.
There are actually 3 potential locations where you can specify the debugging port

1. Php.ini -- {xdebug.remote_port=9000}
2. In Netbeans IDE under - preferences - php - general {debugger port =9000; session ID= netbeans-xdebug}
3. In the run configurations - Advanced  !! DONT set this one - it refers to 'Debugger Proxy' if you set this the browser window will not come up until you have maintained the same proxy settings in the netbeans - preferences - general  tab.

PS: all of the above or on a Mac..

Comment: #3 was a lifesaver.. never saw it mentioned anywhere else, and that has been what was sinking my debug efforts for the last 2 hours on the new machine.  If I could upvote more than once I would!

Comment: it seems to be a gut answer - anyway I can't approve it is working. I'm not using netbeans anymore. this is a often visited question it would be good to have an approved answer.

Comment: I love you bro, the step 3 was the key (on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I had a bad run configuration in project. Netbeans was waiting for a debugging proxi on localhost:9000. I did not remember to set this setting. If someone has the same problem check this configuration too.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem the project URL under Project properties in Run configuration was pointing to a subdirectory instead of the root directory of the server, after i changed to localhost everything was fine.

I found the answer after reading this article.

http://shinephp.com/netbeans-7-0-php-waiting-for-connection-to-xdebug/